# Image Decryption

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, image-processing

The task is to use two pictures as keys (K1,K2) to encrypt an image(I).

The mixing model is E = w1K1 + w2K2 + w3I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to solve a regression problem, where for a given pixel location $i$, you want to map the values $[I(i),K_1(i),K_2(i)]$ to the output $E(i)$. With a single layer network, that's just a linear regression problem, where you need to find the values of the three weights $w_1, w_2, w_3$. So, if you have $n$ pixels, your training set $\{X, y\}$ would consist of a matrix of size $n \times 3$, where each row is made of $[I(i),K_1(i),K_2(i)]$, and $y$ is an $n \times 1$ target vector consisting of the values of $E(i)$. You don't specify which framework you're supposed to be implementing this, but if you were to use the python library keras https://keras.io to do this, then you can potentially build your model as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(3,)))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')
model.fit(X, y)
```